# Disaggregating aggregate GIS data using remote sensing

Tags: raster, analysis, remote-sensing

I haven't really done much with remote sensing imagery. I have census data for an area, and a TIFF raster image of the area.

I'm sure this is possible, is there a simple way to disaggregate the census data to a "per/household" data?

so if let's say the census has a population of 1,000, distribute the population based on the house footprint for example, or lot size

Comment: Do you have an aerial or satellite image? Is the area rural or urban? Do you have any further information available?

Comment: Yes to imagery, well whatever is provided by http://geobase.ca/ the areas i'm looking into are predominantly rural, but there could be light suburban or urban areas as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general approach for performing this kind of disaggregation is through [dasymetric mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasymetric_map), which uses ancillary data to inform the spatial distribution of a phenomenon, and is often used for population analyses, such as this one in [San Francisco](http://geography.wr.usgs.gov/science/dasymetric/index.htm). [This paper](http://astro.temple.edu/~jmennis/pubs/mennis_pg03.pdf) provides good background on the technique, and if you're working in ArcGIS, [scripts have been developed](http://astro.temple.edu/~jmennis/research/dasymetric/) to assist in creating the maps. Unfortunately, there isn't much built-in support for the approach in other packages, though it isn't too difficult to do manually with reclassification.

Paper reference:

```
@article{mennis2003generating,
  title={Generating surface models of population using dasymetric mapping},
  author={Mennis, J.},
  journal={The Professional Geographer},
  volume={55}, number={1}, pages={31--42},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Routledge}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a DOI for the paper?

Comment: +1 good answer. It looks like this method works for vector or raster.

Comment: @dassouki, om_henners: I've updated the link for the paper to the PDF itself, from the author's site.

Comment: @scw - Thanks for providing the second link. On a side note, have you ever used this method, and what's your experience with it?

Comment: @dassouki: We used this method to disaggregate fertilizer and pesticide loads from FAO statistics onto croplands based on a land-cover classification raster for the entire globe, as part of a marine threats analysis.

Comment: @scw Do you work for MarineMap by any chance?

Comment: @scw The link to the paper doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @dassouki seems to be working again, I've also included the ref itself in the article.

Answer (score 2):

[Dr Mitchel Langford](http://staff.southwales.ac.uk/users/309-mlangfor) at the University of Glamorgan has been publishing in this field since at least 1991.  Some relatively recent methods are discussed in:

> Langford M. (2003) “Refining methods
>   for dasymetric mapping using satellite
>   remote sensing”. In: Mesev, V. (Ed)
>   Remotely Sensed Cities, Taylor &
>   Francis: London. p137-156.